# Destructing in DSFML2

Tags: memory, d, sfml

(Compiled with dmd v2.051)

Code like this:

```
import dsfml.graphics.all;

void main()
{   
    while(true)
        auto rect = new Image(1024, 1024);
}
```

Errors out in a minute, throwing an exception. I'd guess it's due to memory leaks.

Code like *this*, on the other hand, causes access violations and/or exceptions:

```
import dsfml.graphics.all;

void main()
{
    auto rect = new Image(1024, 1024);
    rect.dispose();
}
```

What am I actually supposed to do with Images, and other similar classes? I'd like to avoid both memory leaks **and** access violations.

Comment: At a guess, there is an issue where large blocks of data can create false pointers and hold garbage in place. If Image is allocating it's data on the heap and it's not forcing it to be collected imminently and the allocation is not getting marked as "no pointers" then if enough of those accumulate before the GC kicks in, they can deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't look at the code right now, but I think dispose() isn't really meant for public usage.

Remember that DSFML is just a wrapper around CSFML which in turn wraps SFML.
You need to take a lot of care to ensure the user can't break anything.
DSFML is fine for normal usage but can't handle extreme cases like your while(true) loop.

I've been thinking for a while if it would be better to switch to a SWIG-based approach to end this maintenance nightmare. This would probably also make it much easier to use extensions like SFGUI.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out the only real way to solve this and similar problems is to increase the rate at which the garbage collector collects memory.